# React + Webpack Extract Text Plugin. What am I doing wrong? My styles work from bundle.js, but I am trying to move them out to bundle.css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am writing my styles using scss, and I am using css modules so each component has its own styles.

My webpack code is below, but here's my problem.

I would like my prod bundle to have a separate CSS bundle.  I am able to generate a separate CSS `bundle.css`, but none of the mapping between components to the styles.  So, it breaks bootstrap styling.

```
if (__PROD) {
  config = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    context: appPath,
    entry: [
      'main.js'
    ],
    resolve: {
      root: appPath,
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loaders: [
            'babel'
          ],
          include: appPath
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          // loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!postcss!sass'),
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!postcss!sass')
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
        }
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compressor: {
          warnings: false
        }
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
    ],
    postcss: [
      autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 3 versions'] })
    ],
    output: {
      path: buildPath,
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the css file in the `entry`.

```
entry: [
    'main.js',
    'yourFile.css'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am using css modules

You might be using them in your dev config, but you did not enable them in your production config. Add the `modules` option to the `css-loader` in the `ExtractTextPlugin` as well.

```
ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?modules!postcss!sass')
```